# How do you autowire/inject your datasource in Spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-social

I have been working with Spring boot for a bit now, and the datasource is always configured in your application.properties in every example I have seen, kind of like this:

```
# DataSource configuration
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abcdef
spring.datasource.username=******
spring.datasource.password=******
```

However, lately I have been trying to integrate Spring Social, and the examples I have seen configure it in java in a config file like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

This allows for the datasource object to later be injected or autowired into the social config as seen [here](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples/blob/master/sign-in/spring-mvc-normal/src/main/java/net/petrikainulainen/spring/social/signinmvc/config/SocialContext.java) for example.

My question is, do I need to configure a datasource bean like this to be able to later inject the datasource, or will Spring-boot handle that for me?

Comment: You don't need to define the dataSource bean, it will be created by Spring but you need the properties defined and the driver in the classpath.

Comment: Ok cool, so basically the config I listed first? Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have "org.springframework.boot spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" added to your project to make the autoconfiguration work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not a Spring (or Boot) expert by any means, but Spring Boot will auto-provide a Bean of type DataSource if the properties are there and there's a requirement for it. To use it you just `@Autowire` it.

Comment: Ok, so I can just ignore Intellij telling me it can't find a bean of type 'Datasource'?

Comment: Read [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html), and do a test run of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this . If there are multiple @Configuration in springboot , You can import the the other config(DataSourceConfig) into your main AppConfig.
And then Using @PropertySource pull in the db url,username,password etc

https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s03.html

```
@Configuration
    @Import(DataSourceConfig.class)
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class SpringbatchConfig {
        @Autowired
        DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;

        @Bean
        public void myService myService() {
            return new myServiceImpl(dataSourceConfig.dataSource());
        }
    }
```