# How to delete data from all the table present in a list in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a service that takes a list of table names and deletes(truncate) all the data from each table. Each table has a corresponding JPARepository for it. How can I do this in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

You can use native SQL to truncate the tables:

```java
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;


    public void truncateTables(List<String> tableNames) {
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            for (String tableName : tableNames) {
                statement.executeUpdate("TRUNCATE " + tableName);
            }
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
//            error handling...
        }
    }
```

Comment: the DataSource is configured in a @ Configuration class, i have a function under the @ Bean annotation that returns a dataSource.. how can i autowire that?

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666777/how-do-you-autowire-inject-your-datasource-in-spring-boot